# "The user name or password is incorrect" when try access folder from API in IIS

Tags: c#, iis

I have an API need access files under the share folder path.

It would work if I set local path, but would occur error if I set a share folder.

```
string workedPath = "D:\Share\"; //worked
string filePath = "\\10.10.10.10\share\";
var folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
var files = folderInfo.GetFiles("*.csv").ToList(); //show error "The user name or password is incorrect"
```

I tried open "\\10.10.10.10\share" on IIS Server.

It can directly access the folder without input account and password.

I don't understand why it would show error that ask to input password when access folder using API.

Is there anything need set on IIS or something?

Comment: Did you check if the application pool user have access to the shared folder ?

Comment: "I tried open "\\10.10.10.10\share" on IIS Server" is using your powerful user account.  "The user name or password is incorrect" because your code runs under the application pool identity. There are tons of key differences you must get familiar with, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Please check your Application Pool Identity, make sure it has the correct permission, and make sure "Load User Profile" to True in Application Pool option "Load User Profile".